# Uploading PDF file on next js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file, next.js

I'm trying to upload PDF file (CV) on next js , everything is fine according to my expectation but in backend when I

> console.log(req.data)

it shows me

> [object:object]

**note**
When I console.log the data in frontend its work fine and I see all the data including file in form but in backend I'm unable to get that data

1. I tried config bodyparser to false in next API if I do that I won't received any data in backend

how can I fix this issue

**Post Request**

```
export const apply_job = async (formData) => {
    console.log(formData)
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/job/applyJob`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers : {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body: formData,
          });
        const data = await res.json();
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error in apply job (service) => ', error);
    }
}
```

**frontend Code**

```
import NavBar from '@/components/NavBar';
import { apply_job } from '@/Services/job';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

export default function ApplyJob() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { id } = router.query
    const user = useSelector(state => state.User.userData)
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: '', email: "", about: '', job: id, user: user?._id, cv: null })
    const [error, setError] = useState({ name: '', email: "", about: '', job: '', user: '', cv: '' });


    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();




        if (!formData.name) {
            setError({ ...error, name: "Name Field is required" })
            return;
        }

        if (!formData.email) {
            setError({ ...error, email: "Email Field is required" })
            return;
        }


        if (!formData.user) {
            return toast.error('Please Login First')
        }
        if (!formData.job) {
            return toast.error('Please Follow Apply Process ')
        }
        if (!formData.about) {
            setError({ ...error, about: "About Field is required" })
            return;
        }
        if (!formData.cv) {
            setError({ ...error, cv: "Please Upload CV" })
            return;
        }
        console.log(formData)

        const res = await apply_job(formData);
        // if (res.success) {
        //     toast.success(res.message)
        // } else {
        //     toast.error(res.message)
        // }

    }

    return (
        <>
            <NavBar />
            <div className='w-full  py-20 flex items-center  justify-center flex-col'>
                <h1 className='text-xl mt-4 uppercase tracking-widest border-b-2 border-b-indigo-600 py-2 font-semibold mb-8 md:text-2xl lg:text-4xl'>Enter Your Info</h1>
                <form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="sm:w-1/2 w-full px-4 mx-4  h-full" >
                    <div className='w-full mb-4  flex flex-col items-start justify-center'>
                        <label htmlFor="title" className='mb-1 text-base font-semibold'>Name :</label>
                        <input onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, name: e.target.value })} type="text" id='title' className='w-full py-2 px-3 mb-2 border border-indigo-600 rounded' placeholder='Enter Name ' />
                        {
                            error.name && <p className="text-sm text-red-500">{error.name}</p>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className='w-full mb-4  flex flex-col items-start justify-center'>
                        <label htmlFor="email" className='mb-1 text-base font-semibold'>Email :</label>
                        <input onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, email: e.target.value })} type="email" id='email' className='w-full py-2 px-3 mb-2 border border-indigo-600 rounded' placeholder='Enter Email' />
                        {
                            error.email && <p className="text-sm text-red-500">{error.email}</p>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className='w-full mb-4  flex flex-col items-start justify-center'>
                        <label htmlFor="description" className='mb-1 text-base font-semibold'>About :</label>
                        <textarea onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, about: e.target.value })} type="description" id='description' className='w-full py-2 px-3 mb-2 border border-indigo-600 rounded' placeholder='Enter description' />
                        {
                            error.about && <p className="text-sm text-red-500">{error.about}</p>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className='w-full mb-4  flex flex-col items-start justify-center'>
                        <label htmlFor="file" className='mb-1 text-base font-semibold'>Upload CV :</label>
                        <input name='cv' onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, cv: e.target.files[0] })} type="file" id='file' className='w-full py-2 px-3 mb-2 border border-indigo-600 rounded' placeholder='Enter Email' />
                        {
                            error.cv && <p className="text-sm text-red-500">{error.cv}</p>
                        }
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" className='w-full py-2 rounded bg-indigo-600 text-white font-semibold tracking-widest'>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ToastContainer />
        </>
    )
}
```

**backend code**

```
import ConnectDB from '@/DB/connectDB';
import AppliedJob from '@/models/ApplyJob';
import Joi from 'joi';


const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    about: Joi.string().required(),
    job: Joi.string().required(),
    user: Joi.string().required(),
});


export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: {
            sizeLimit: '50mb' // Set desired value here
        }
    }
}


export default async (req, res) => {
    await ConnectDB();

    const data = req.body;
    console.log(data)


    // const { name, email, job, user, about , cv} = data;
    // const { error } = schema.validate({ name, email, job, user, about});

    // if (error) return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: error.details[0].message.replace(/['"]+/g, '') });


    // try {
    //     const creatingUser =  await AppliedJob.create({user , title,description , salary , company , email , job_category , job_type , job_experience , job_vacancy , job_deadline });
    //     return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Job Posted Successfully !" })
    // } catch (error) {
    //     console.log('Error in posting a job (server) => ', error);
    //     return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Something Went Wrong Please Retry Later !" })
    // }
}
```

Comment: In your api config, you might need to disable next.js's default parser, with `bodyParser: false,` and implement your own. This short [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTD9L0jL0dU) might help :)

Comment: I have already Tried that :) doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In your frontend code you need to initialize a Javascript `formData` object like this: `const formData = new FormData()`

Before sending your data you need to add each input to the `formData` object e.g.
`formData.append("name", nameInput)` then send the formData object in the request body. No `content-type` header is required since the browser automatically detects the `FormData` object and assigns the `multipart/form-data` header with a boundary

```
const response = await fetch(URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {},
        body: formData,
      });
```

In your backend code you need to use `formidable` to parse the form data that's been sent to your endpoint. It should look something like this:

```
const form = formidable()
await form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
  console.log("fields:", fields)
  console.log("files:", files)
}
```